# Sentinel interfering with finding minumum value in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program that takes in grades of an exam.(once the user is done inputting the grades he should press -1. the program should find the max and min grade and compute the average of all the grades.
My problem is that -1 is always the minumum grade computed. i tried fixing this problem by putting intmain1=999 (a very large number), but it also didnt work.
any suggestions?
thank you so much!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int grade1,average1;
int max1=0;
int min1=0;
int counter=0;
int sum=0;
    cout<<"Enter grades of quiz 1. Use '-1' when there are no more grades."<<endl;
    cin>>grade1;
while (grade1!=-1){
    cin>>grade1;
    counter++;
    sum=sum+grade1;
    if (grade1>max1)
        max1=grade1;
    else if (grade1<min1)
        min1=grade1;
}
average1=sum/counter;
cout<<"The maximum grade of quiz 1 is"<<max1<<endl;
cout<<"The minumum grade of quiz 1 is"<<min1<<endl;
cout<<"THe average of quiz one is"<<average1<<endl;
```

}

Comment: `cin>>grade1;` should be the last instruction of your `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is move the `cin>>grade1;` from the first line of your while loop to the last. As your code is written, once they enter -1 it does all the logic in the loop and then finally stops, where you want it to stop before processing the -1.